# One client VPN certificate for whole company, different passwords

Tags: vpn

What are the security concerns, when using OpenVPN and whole company has one client certificate, but for each client, it is exported with different password?

Should each client has its own certificate or is this solution acceptable to some degree?

Thank You

Comment: You need to give us more context. Please edit your question to better explain the network. Also, OpenVPN is usually configured on a server and it would be off-topic here, but you could ask about it on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The acceptability depends entirely on the VPN partner and your policies and risk assessment.  Obviously, with one certificate, it will be difficult to know which user is connected to the VPN.  If that's not a problem for you or your VPN partner, then it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Each client should have its own certificate.  When you eventually need to revoke the certificate, you'll lock out all your clients.  For example if someone leaves the company, or a certain computer is compromised, you'll want to revoke that client certificate without affecting the rest of the clients.